# Cannot get MEAN app deployed to Heroku because of “ No default language could be detected for this app.”

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a MEAN app to Heroku, but cannot push due to the following error:

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
        HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
!     Push failed
```

I tried setting a node.js buildpack with their latest node buildpack release, but just received another error:

```
failed to detect buildpack
```

This is my first deployment to Heroku, so I'm brand new at this.

Here are my package.jsons:

## Server

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.2",
    "debug": "^2.6.3",
    "ejs": "~2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.2",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

## Client

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.0",
    "amcharts3-angular2": "github:amcharts/amcharts3-angular2",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Why is Heroku not detecting Node?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

> To determine how to start your app, Heroku first looks for a Procfile.
>   If no Procfile exists for a Node.js app, we will attempt to start a
>   default web process via the start script in your package.json.

So you shouldn't need to set the build pack.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I installed it because I originally received this error:

!     No default language could be detected for this app.
   HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed

Comment: Try setting the start script in the`package.json`. Like `"scripts" : { "start" : "node server.js" }`.

Comment: I added my package.jsons so people can see my dependencies.  I tried changing the scripts start, but keep receiving the same error.

Comment: You won't be able to use `nodemon` on Heroku. Just use `node ./bin/www` instead. Since this is your first deployment, it might be worthwhile to try a `ZFR` zero feature release, just the minimum code to get a node application running, then add your application functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have two package.jsons, one for client and one for server.  I needed to put my server dependencies into the root folder (they were each nested in client and server folders, respectively).  Moving it into root made it detectable by heroku.  Of course, now I have a new error.  :)